# URL Link to open a Activity detail task in Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a Visualforce page that has the list of activity.  Currently, they are only list but would like to have a link so they can open the detailed task. I would like to know what am I missing as far as coding the URL link and if you can help me on the code.  Thanks guys.

Sample VF Image
[image]

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ActivityHistoryOnContact" showHeader="true" sidebar="false" >
<div style="overflow: scroll; height: 600px;">
  <apex:pageBlock title="Activity History">
      <apex:pageBlockSection >
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ListTasks}" var="tsk" html-cid="actTable" style="width:1200px" >
          <apex:column style="width:500px" headerValue="Date" value="{!tsk.LastModifiedDate}" />
          <apex:column style="width:500px" headerValue="Activity" value="{!tsk.Id}" />
              <apex:column style="width:900px" headerValue="Subject" value="/{!tsk.Subject}" />
              <apex:column style="width:2500px" headerValue="Comments" value="{!tsk.Description}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:pageBlockSection> 
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </div>
</apex:page>
```

APEX CLASS

```
 public class ActivityHistoryOnContact{


 public String currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();
 public String currentContact =      ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
public String taskList {get;set;}
public String soql {get;set;}



public Task[] getListTasks() {

  //                       taskList = 'select      whoid,subject,status,LastModifiedDate, WhatID, Description, Primary_Contact_Phone_Number__c, Primary_Contact_Email_Address__c, Call_Result__c, Last_Call_Date__c, Last_Call_Agent__c from task WHERE CreatedbyId=\''+currentUser+'\' AND (subject LIKE \'call%\' OR subject LIKE \'outbound%\') AND WhoID =\''+currentContact+'\' order by LastModifiedDate desc limit 20000'; 
   taskList = 'select whoid,subject,status,LastModifiedDate, WhatID, Description, Primary_Contact_Phone_Number__c, Primary_Contact_Email_Address__c, Call_Result__c, Last_Call_Date__c, Last_Call_Agent__c from task WHERE CreatedbyId=\''+currentUser+'\' AND WhoID =\''+currentContact+'\' order by LastModifiedDate desc limit 20000';  


    //delete duplicate property records
         List<Task> tskList = Database.query(taskList);
         System.debug('#########tskListInit'+tskList);

              System.debug('#########tskListFinal'+tskList);
          return tskList;     

}
public ActivityHistoryOnContact(ApexPages.StandardController controller){}    
}
```

Comment: I've tried the...
<apex:outputlink>, Hyperlink, URL and nothing works.  I put them below the column.

Comment: @NinjaKing facing any issue. when you tried `<apex:outputlink>` ?

Comment: @Ratan yah.  here's my code...
<apex:column style="width:500px" headerValue="Activity" value="{!tsk.Id}" />
          <apex:outputLink value="/{!tsk.id}">{!tsk.id}</apex:outputLink>

Comment: still nothing.  All I get is tsk.id but no link.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I tried outputlink, Hyperlink and URL and still nothing.

Comment: @NinjaKing hey `<apex:column style="width:500px" headerValue="Activity" > <apex:outputLink value="/{!tsk.id}">{!tsk.id}</apex:outputLink></apex:column>`  remove value from apex:column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey you need to use like this.. Wrap your link inside apex:column

```
<apex:column style="width:500px" headerValue="Activity" > 
  <apex:outputLink value="/{!tsk.id}">{!tsk.id}</apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

Comment: I added the </apex:column> it giving me an error:ActivityHistoryOnContact line 8, column 76: The element type "apex:pageblocktable" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:pageblocktable>"

Comment: made some changes and the link works I just need to open the URL on a diffrent tab.  Thanks